# android: radio button option retrieval

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a radio group in android containing 3 options. Plus i also have a button named checked. I want to select option 1 when i click the button "checked". Here's what i am doing:

```
RadioGroup options;
    RadioButton rb;
    TextView txt;
    CharSequence userMsg;
    Button checked;
    int id;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        options=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.options);
        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

options.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
                userMsg=rb.getText();
                txt.setText(userMsg);
            }
        });
checked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        options.check(1);


    }
});


    }
}
```

It gives me null pointer exception error.Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in your Button `onClick` function

```
tRadioButton.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Button checked` is initialized to `null`.

Initialize by:

```
Button checked = (button) findViewById(...);
```